# ubuntu freezes right after loading

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

new install of ubuntu 12.04 i386 desktop.iso on a toshiba satellite intel celeron m gets to the desktop screen and freezes the mouse still moves but nothing responds to it started terminal by pressing ctl+alt+f1 tried "startx" and got this(i cant copy and paste but i will do my best to avoid typos):

fatal server error:
server is already active for display 0
        if this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again

please consult the x.org foundation support for help

ddxSgiveup: closing log
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (resource temporarily unavailable) on x server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
xxxxxx@aaaaaa-Satellite-a105:~$

tried "startx --:1" just took me back to the default wallpaper with nothing else mouse still moves but nothing else